# Check a new proof of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: proof-verification

Is my proof below original?

We prove Fermat's little theorem in the reduced formulation:
*If
$p$
is an odd prime and
$a$
is an integer such that
$p < a$
and
$p \nmid a,$
then
$a^{p-1} \equiv 1\ (mod\ p).$*

Note,
since
$p$
is an odd prime,
that the congruence
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1\ (mod\ p)$$
is equivalent to the congruence
$$(a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} - 1)(a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} + 1) \equiv 0\ \ (mod\ p).$$
If
$$p \nmid (a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} - 1)\ \ \ and\ \ \ p \nmid (a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} + 1),$$
then there exist integers
$q, r, q', r' > 0$
such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} &=& pq + r + 1,\ \ 1 \leq r \leq p-1,\\
a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} &=& pq' + r' - 1,\ \ 1 \leq r' \leq p-1,
\end{eqnarray*}
so that
$$p(q' - q) = r - r' + 2,$$
whence
$$p \mid (r - r' + 2),$$
and we have
$$r - r' \geq p - 2.$$
So,
since
$1 \leq r, r' \leq p-1,$
certainly
$$r - r' = p-2.$$
With no loss of generality,
put
$$r := p-1,\ \ r' := 1.$$
But then
$$p \mid a^{\frac{p-1}{2}};$$
a contradiction.

Comment: I think you need to give more context to your question. One of my questions on this site was "have you found this result proved this way" - a well known result with many proofs. Or are you talking about a new result?

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thanks. But I am after a general method to check the originality of a new proof of a well-known result. It was my fault to choose a wrong tag.

Comment: A new proof of a known result or a proof of a new result?

Comment: well-known result

Comment: It *is* possible to find new proofs for well-known results (even for good ol' Pathagoras). Browsing the internet is however a very incomplete method to compare against other proofs, unless you encounter a note specifically investigating the history of proofs of theorem X, say. Why not publish your proof here and see if the community "remembers" it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please see the revision.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Please see the revision.

Comment: Ideas? Original?

Comment: Why is $r-r'\ge p-2$? Why is $q=q'$, $r=r'-2$ excluded?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: So is it an unfixable flaw? Thanks.